# Help with understanding theorem

Tags: real-analysis

I have a question regarding the proof of a theorem regarding subsequences. The theorem (the first part) states:
If $t$ is in $R$, then there is a subsequence  of $(s_n)$ converging to $t$ if and only if the set $\{n\in N:|s_n-t|<\epsilon\}$ is infinite or all $\epsilon>0$.

The proof (the portion I'm wondering about) goes as follows:
Assume the set $\{n \in N:s_n=t\}$ is finite. Then $\{n \in N:0<|s_n-t|<\epsilon\}$ if infinite for all $\epsilon>0$. Since these sets equal

$\{n \in N:t-\epsilon<s_n<t\}U\{n \in N:t<s_n<t+\epsilon\}$, and these sets get smaller as $\epsilon$ approaches $0$, we have $\{n \in N:t-\epsilon<s_n<t\}$

or

$\{n \in N:t<s_n<t+\epsilon\}$ for all $\epsilon>0$

My question is how is the first two sets equal the union of the two sets.

Comment: This comes from the Ross' book of Elementary Analysis and think that where it says "these sets" it should be "this set."

Comment: No, it is "these sets". One for each $\epsilon>0$. Do you understand how to solve inequalities involving absolute values? $|a|<b$ iff ... ? Or $b<|a|$ iff ...?

Answer (score 1):

Let's forget what your book says, and show the "$\Rightarrow$" direction by proving the contrapositve statement:

Suppose $\{n \in N : |s_n - t| < \epsilon \}  \quad \forall \epsilon >0$. We want to show that  no subsequence of $(s_n)$ converges to $t$. Suppose there *is* a subsequence of $(s_n)$ converging to $t$, say $(s_{n_k})$. Then $\exists K \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $k \geq K \Rightarrow |s_{n_k} - t| < 1.$ This shows that the set  $\{n \in N : |s_n - t| < 1 \}$ is infinite, as all terms in $(s_{n_k})$ are terms in $(s_n)$. This contradicts our hypothesis (picking $\epsilon = 1 > 0 $). So indeed there is no subsequence of $(s_n)$ which converges to $t$.